# Why does the callback in this Mongo query never get called?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In the following query the callback function never fires.  It's almost a verbatim clone of a query that works fine elsewhere in my application.  So I can't figure out what the problem is.  Can someone spot what I've done wrong?

```
var imagesCollection = db.collection('Images');

    var Images = new Array();

    while(Images.length < quantity) {
        var random = Math.random();

            imagesCollection.find({
                "audioFiles.audioLanguage": audioLanguage,
                "random": {
                    $lte: random
                }
            }).limit(1, function(err, doc) {
                console.log('This never gets called');
                Images.push(doc);
            });

    }
    callback(err, Images);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop is effectively an infinite loop because the `find` callbacks can't be called as long as the loop is running, and the loop only exits once enough callbacks have run.

Also, `limit` passes the cursor to the callback, not the doc, so you should use `findOne` instead.

You'd need to rewrite it to be something like:

```
var imagesCollection = db.collection('Images');
var Images = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
    var random = Math.random();
    imagesCollection.findOne({
        "audioFiles.audioLanguage": audioLanguage,
        "random": {
            $lte: random
        }
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (Images.push(doc) === quantity) {
            callback(err, Images);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be pushing the same doc repeatedly into the array rather than performing the query n times and pushing each result into the array.  Could the loop be finishing faster than the query operations?

Comment: @hughesdan The loop will finish before the first callback is called, but that's expected.  If the same doc is getting pushed multiple times it may be an issue with the `random` part of this.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the random part works.  What seems to be happening is the result of the first firing of the query gets pushed into the array multiple times before the next firing of the query returns.  However, I think you've answered the original question regarding the while loop.  I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
quantity

var quantity = 10;  //declare variable to whatever number it needs to be
var imagesCollection = db.collection('Images');
var Images = new Array();

while(Images.length < quantity) {
//rest of code here...
```

See if that helps you out.

Comment: That's not the issue.  Quantity is declared elsewhere in my code.  I just didn't show that above.